# Why shouldn't I provide services in components in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

If I want to use service across the whole app, I should declare it as provider in `app.module.ts`, but it also works if it is declared in `app.component.ts`.

Is there any significant difference in those two approaches?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's say you have three components that are declared in your `AppModule`. If you provide service individually in every component, each of them will have its own instance of service, but if you provide it in `AppModule`, your service will be singleton - each component will share **one same instance** of that service.

Answer (score 0):

Using `app.module.ts` vs `app.component.ts` is just a [naming convention](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#symbols-and-file-names) and doesn't programmitcally determine anything in Angular. The code will work wherever your service lives. It may make more sense to instead put your services into a [`service-name.service.ts`](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#service-names) file, not in `app.module.ts`. Either place however, as indicated in Stefan Svrkota's answer, you get the advantage of code reuse

Comment: This answer is misleading. By convention one expects app.module.ts to be a module and app.component.ts to be a component - they are two very different things. It is not, as this answer suggests, the same file with 2 different names.

Comment: I was just responding to " but it also works if it is declared in app.component.ts" -- That the naming convention is just a convention is not determining anything in Angular.